# Is Turkey trading oil with Islamic State?

Tags: politics, russia, terrorism, turkey, syria

Russia claims Turkey is trading oil with Islamic State:

- [Syria conflict: Russia accuses Erdogan of trading oil with IS](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-middle-east-34982951) (BBC News, 2 December 2015)
- [Russia presents proof of Turkey’s role in ISIS oil trade](https://www.rt.com/news/324263-russia-briefing-isis-funding/) (Russia Today, 2 December 2015).

Does the evidence presented by Russia show indeed that Turkey is trading oil with IS?

Comment: GREAT question, I was about to ask that myself!

Comment: It is worth mentioning that Erdoğan said he would resign if it was proven that Turkey is doing this. Russia has accused Erdoğan himself of profiting off of the oil and has said that a family member recently purchased oil tankers for this reason. This is one of the stories ran by Sputnik, but there are many stories from Sputnik and RT concerning these topics (this one article doesn't make all the claims):
http://sputniknews.com/analysis/20151201/1031078172/turkey-involved-daesh-oil-smuggling.html

Comment: Here is another good source of the Russian claims: http://sputniknews.com/middleeast/20151201/1031041612/erdogan-turkey-oil-proof.html

Comment: [Same question at Politics.SE](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9466/is-turkey-really-buying-isis-oil-like-russia-says), which doesn't have any rule against events currently under investigation.